PHP - Get response URL from external cgi-bin
I am trying to get to a jpg from a cgi-bin script from an API call.
When I call the API I get this URL: https://www.example.com/cgi-bin/public/search.cgi/photo_url?id=29846404&clan_id=1
When I open that link in a browser it resolves to: https://uploads.example.com/6/2/b/513429697.jpg which is the jpg I want.
In PHP how can I get access to the response URL when all I have is cgi-bin url?
I tried cURL and Laravel Http Client but I just get a 403 error response.
$url = 'https://www.example.com/cgi-bin/public/search.cgi/photo_url?id=29846404&clan_id=1';
$response = Http::get($url);

UPDATED
$url = 'https://www.adoptapet.com/cgi-bin/public/petsearch.cgi/photo_url?pet_id=29846404&clan_id=1';
$ch = curl_init();
    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
));
    
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

dd($response);

I am still getting a 403 error

Sounds like the remote site is issuing a redirect header which your code is not following. You likely need to set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION on your client, however that's done for Laravel. Looks like maybe Http::globalOptions(['allow_redirects' => true]);

Interesting, I tried that and still get the 403 error. In Laravel do I need to pass different headers than 'application/json' on the GET request?

A 403 response means you're not authorized. Perhaps it's expecting an Authorization header or some cookies? When you visit the URL in the browser, check in the Network Inspector what information your browser sends with the request (headers, URL query parameters, etc.) and compare that with what you're sending from PHP.

You haven't shown any JSON so I'm not sure why you be providing that header. 403 could indicate that the remote site is trying to block what it thinks is bots. Maybe set your user agent string to something that emualtes a browser? Something like Http::withUserAgent($agent)->get($url); where $agent is a valid user agent string.

Looking at the inspector right now. Heres the URL: https://www.adoptapet.com/cgi-bin/public/petsearch.cgi/photo_url?pet_id=29846404&clan_id=1

You're being blocked by CloudFront because you look like a bot.
% curl -s -D - 'https://www.adoptapet.com/cgi-bin/...'

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: CloudFront
...
Request blocked.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.

Change your User-Agent string so that you look like a browser. You then get the JPG URL as a Location header, which you can either manually extract or simply let your client automatically follow.
% curl -s -D - -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 ...' 'https://www.adoptapet.com/cgi-bin/...'

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 237
...
Location: https://pet-uploads.adoptapet.com/6/2/b/513429697.jpg

You can find current User-Agent strings here. For this example, I used Chrome's:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
[UPDATE]
You don't need to switch to CURL, my code is just an example. You can continue to use Laravel. If you want the contents of the image as a big binary string, just request the original URL and Laravel will automatically follow redirects:
$image = Http::withUserAgent($agent)->get($url)->body();

If you want the image URL, disable redirects and read the Location header:
Http::globalOptions(['allow_redirects' => false]);
$url = Http::withUserAgent($agent)->get($url)->header('Location');


curl -s -D - -H 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' 'https://www.adoptapet.com/cgi-bin/public/petsearch.cgi/photo_url?pet_id=29846404&clan_id=1' I still get the block message

You need to provide the header name: -H 'User-Agent: ...

Ahhh duh. It works. Now I am trying to convert it to php curl and still getting the 403. Updated my question with the code above

Your code works fine for me, but you don't have to use CURL. See my updated answer.

I would argue they don't "look like" a bot, they are one.

It appears cloudfront is blocking digitalocean server IPs. Found another solution. Thanks for your help
